# Como implementar UI como o recent do Lolipop

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

estou tentando implementar UI como o recent do Lolipop preciso saber se é possível e se  posso faze-lo com RecyclerView e CardView?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, é importante saber que o Android Lollipop utiliza o [Material Design](http://www.google.com.br/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#), que é um conjunto de práticas e padrões de design ( [cores](http://www.google.com.br/design/spec/style/color.html), [ícones](http://www.google.com.br/design/spec/style/icons.html),
   [tipografia](http://www.google.com.br/design/spec/style/typography.html), [animações](http://www.google.com.br/design/spec/animation/authentic-motion.html), [layouts](http://www.google.com.br/design/spec/layout/principles.html), etc). Portanto, se
   você seguir estas regras do Material Design, o seu app ficará com uma
   ótima UI.

E sim, é possível( e recomendável ) implementar o Material Design usando Recycler Views e Card Views. Lembrando que se você for implementar o Material Design em dispositivos com API inferior a do Lollipop, será necessário você utilizar a [biblioteca de suporte](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) adequada. Aqui está exemplo de como implementar a UI do Lollipop.

https://tasafo.wordpress.com/2015/03/23/utilizando-material-design-em-android/